# Algebra Linear transformations Kernel and range

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

if **u** = $(u_1,u_2,u_3) \in \Re^3 $and  **v** $=(v_1,v_2) \in \Re^2$ be non-zero vectors, with **F** : $\Re^3 \to \Re^2$ by **F(x) = (u.x)v.**

show that ker ***F*** = (span {**u**})$^\bot$ and that Range (***F***) = span {**v**}. also that the stantard matrix of F is **v**$^t$**u**.

any help or advice will be greatful as i am stuck on even how to comprehend the question, thankyou for any help

Answer (score 1):

it is enough you take $x\in(span{u})^\perp‎‎‎‎$ then by definision $(u.x)=0$  thus $F(x)=0$ hence$x\in ker F$. 
Now suppose $x\in ker F$ then $(u.x)v=0$ since $v$ isnot zero, we have $(u.x)=0$, so $x\in (span {u})^\perp‎‎‎‎$. It is clearly that $rangF\subseteq{‎spanv}$, for inverse inclusion suppose $\sum^n_{k=1} a_i v\in span{v}$ since $F$ is linear it is sufficient to show $a_i v\in rangF$ or for some $x$, $u.x=a_i$, which I think there is no doubt that this equation has answer.

Comment: im sorry, i didnt really understand what you are meaning, can you explain how $x\in(span{u})^\perp‎‎‎‎$ defines (u.x)=0? thankyou

Comment: dontnot forget that $u\in span{u}$, thus $x\in(span{u})^\perp‎‎‎‎$ given $(u.x)=0$